# How to align the widget to center in QTabWidget?

Tags: user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

[image]

As you can see, I added a login widget to the QTabWidget (My login tab has a fixed size by the way), I want to align the login widget to the center, How can I do that?

It doesn't have alignment for the widget under the tabs I think.

Comment: You can put your login widget in a widget with a layout, and add that widget to the tabwidget.

Comment: My login widget is in a layout, I fixed the size of the login widget to prevent the stretch.

Comment: Then add stretch factors to that layout or properly use alignments. If you want more help, provide a [mre], we cannot guess things just by looking at an image.